# Is moving to Lion a prerequisite for moving to XCode 4.1 (from the app store)?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, osx-lion

should you only download XCode 4.1 from the app store if you move to Lion?

i.e I am staying on Leopard for a few more weeks, so do I have to stay with XCode 4.0.2 until I move to Lion?

Comment: Had you tried, you would know that you need Lion.

Comment: That may have been true for Xcode 4.1—I don't recall—but Xcode 4.2 is available for both Lion and Snow Leopard, if you download it from the iOS Developer Centre while logged in as a registered developer. It is not, however, available for Leopard, which of course is what the OP was asking about.

Comment: This is an old question, the question and the answers might be only relevant at the time this was asked. Perhaps we should stop digging this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it seems:

> This is a pre-release version of Xcode 4.1 for both Mac and iOS development. This release requires Mac OS X Lion and includes iOS SDK 4.2. Continue to use Xcode 3.2.5 on a Snow Leopard partition if you plan to submit Mac or iOS apps to the App Store

Details: http://thetechjournal.com/electronics/computer/software/xcode-4-1-developer-preview-for-mac-os-x-lion-is-available-for-download.xhtml#ixzz1TGiXaC1w

UPDATE: This question was asked in Jul 2011. As of now, Nov 2011, Xcode 4.2 is already released and made available on the Mac App store.

Comment: Xcode 4.2 is available for both Lion and Snow Leopard, if you download it from the iOS Developer Centre while logged in as a registered developer

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Xcode 4.1 Requires Lion. This has been well documented, but 4.2 is apparently available for Snow Leopard as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes moving to Lion is a requirement.  4.1 brings all of the Lion features into the Xcode environment.  I would say if you aren't ready to move to Lion yet, then just stick with 4.0.2 unless you need to develop for Lion.

UPDATE: As of Xcode 4.2, it is now for both Lion and Snow Leopard.

Comment: Xcode 4.2 is available for both Lion and Snow Leopard, if you download it from the iOS Developer Centre while logged in as a registered developer

Comment: When I initially posted this 4.1 was Lion only, but now it's for both with 4.2.  I'll edit my response, and thanks for the down vote.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 4.2 is available for both Lion and Snow Leopard, if you download it from the iOS Developer Centre while logged in as a registered developer. The Mac App Store will only upgrade you to Xcode 4.2 if you upgrade to Lion, but you can manually install it on Snow Leopard by manually downloading it as described here, and it runs just fine on Snow Leopard.