# Xcode 4.3.2 is missing iOS 4.0 simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, ios-simulator, simulator

I have the latest version of Xcode (4.3.2) and have set `Deployment Target` to 4.0. But there is not iOS 4.0 simulator only 4.3 and above.

[image]

Is there an easy way to install iOS 4.0 Simulator in Xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple has stopped supporting devices running operating system previous to iOS 4.3 in their Xcode 4.3.2 SDK. So for that you might need to install the previous SDK of Xcode

Comment: I've installed Xcode 3.2.5 on Lion but the problem is ARC. The Xcode does not recognize it. So the whole project is worthless building here...

Comment: i think this answers your question :                          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838774/is-moving-to-lion-a-prerequisite-for-moving-to-xcode-4-1-from-the-app-store

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to add a (new) simulator

1. Click on **Simulator** icon and open simulator list.
2. At the end of list, there is an option to add new simulator "**Add Additional Simulator**". That will open **'Device & Simulator'** window.
3. Switch to **'Simulator'** tab.
4. There are three field in simulator tab.
5. Click on **'+'** icon, on left bottom corner of window.
6. Simulator Name: *Enter simulator name here*
7. Device Type: *Select **iPad** from this dropdown list*
8. OS Version: *Select OS version from this dropdown list*
9. Click on **'Create'**

A new simulator will be added in your Simulator option list.

Look at this snapshot to understand flow of above steps:
[image]

And if there is no simulator/OS version in simulator list, you're looking for,

1. Click on **Simulator** icon and open simulator list.
2. At the end of list, there is an option to add new simulator "**Download Simulator**". That will open **'Component'** window (from Xcode >> Preferences).
3. Select/click simulator from list, which you need to download.

Look at this snapshot:
[image]